# Capistrano db:reset not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, capistrano

I have a rails app in AWS. I need to run db:reset with Capistrano and I have tried 2 different gems (capistrano-rails-db and capistrano-rails-collection), but it is not working. I tried also a [recipe](http://jessewolgamott.com/blog/2012/09/10/the-one-where-you-run-rake-commands-with-capistrano/) that I found  but it is not working. The migration doesn't show an error but still not migrating the new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
cap deploy:invoke task="db:reset"
```

Sample usage :

```
cap staging deploy:invoke task=db:seed
cap deploy:invoke task=another:rake-task
```

or this:

```
bundle exec cap db:reset


namespace :db do
  desc 'Resets DB without create/drop'
  task :reset do
    on primary :db do
      within release_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:stage) do
          execute :rake, 'db:schema:load'
          execute :rake, 'db:seed'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You should write namespace code in your respective deploy environment files